# Trying to use Angular Virtual Keyboard module in my Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I am trying to follow the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/the-darc/angular-virtual-keyboard

Under "Usage" it says:

"1) Import the angular-virtual-keyboard.min.js script in your page." - what does that mean? Should I include the "script src=" element in my index.html?

2) "Include the module angular-virtual-keyboard in your angular app" - how exactly am I supposed to do that? By modifying app.module.ts?

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use [Mottie virtual Keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard),it is a great keyboard.I successfully used with angular 4 cli/systemjs.config.js but not with webpack

Install/add jquery to your project

then

```
 <input type="text" id="mycontrol">
...
    declare var $: any;

    ngAfterViewInit(): any {

        $('#mycontrol').keyboard();

      }
```

see docs folder for examples (and also see what js/css files are needed)

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

People in Angular google group explained to me that is was not even Angular 2 plugin. It is an Angular 1 plugin.